# How to manage notification when users click on badge

Tags: iphone, uitableview, onclick, push-notification, badge

I have a question to ask about notifications. After some hours to learn how to implement push notifications on iPhone, it now arrives!

How do I manage users that click on badge or click view on alert? What happen when users click there?

I tried to send me some notification and the number on the icon of application in springboard increments.  In which way clicking there it's possible to show a uiview to manage the notification arrived and show the message read and unread?

Is there a tutorial for it? I want to save all the messages inside a uitableview.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want to read [Handling Local and Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4)

Basically in your application delegate, you want to implement:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

And process the launchOptions / userInfo for the notification data.

How I normally process the data is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary* userInfo =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (userInfo) {
        [self processRemoteNotification:userInfo];
    }
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [self processRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

The format for userInfo is documented the [The Notification Payload](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) section.

e.g. the "aps" key will give you another NSDictionary, then looking up the "alert" key will give you the alert message that was displayed.  Also, any custom data you send in the JSON payload will be in there as well.

```
NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

NSString *alertMsg = @"";
NSString *badge = @"";
NSString *sound = @"";
NSString *custom = @"";

if( [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"] != NULL)
{
    alertMsg = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"]; 
}


if( [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] != NULL)
{
    badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"]; 
}


if( [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"] != NULL)
{
    sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"]; 
}

if( [userInfo objectForKey:@"Custom"] != NULL)
{
    custom = [userInfo objectForKey:@"Custom"];
}
```

Comment: I just followed the info on apple's site and didn't have any problems.  What exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: Updated answer with the info you wanted.